# Выделение части изображения

Tags: c#, wpf

Как наиболее лаконично и правильно реализовать подобный интерфейс?

Есть отдельное модальное окно. В нем Image, в Image соответственно картинка.

Как создать на нем рамку прозрачную в центре и "затуманенную" по краям, чтобы этой рамкой можно было выделить часть изображения?

Рамку, разумеется, надо двигать и изменять размеры.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20245/WPF-Interactive-Image-Cropping-Control и еще тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240261/crop-image-using-canvas-rectangle

Comment: Это я видел. Я не могу понять как организовать обратный эффект. Что бы "окошко" было прозрачным, а края закрыты фильтром

Comment: если бы внимательно прочли статью по ссылке номер 1, то заметили бы там ссылку со скриншотом на другую статью http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23158/A-Photoshop-like-Cropping-Adorner-for-WPF

Comment: По поводу кропинга картинок в интернете статей больше чем книжек по языкам программирования

Comment: Да, как раз читаю. Благодарю.